# VueJS - "npm run build" does not generate index.html file in dist folder

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, html-webpack-plugin

I have developed a VueJS project. After I run the command

```
npm run build
```

a dist folder containing a build.js file, and an image, gets generated.

But there is no index.html file in /dist.

My Project structure looks like this

[image: Folder structure]

And my webpack.config.js looks like this

```js
let path = require('path');

let webpack = require('webpack');

let UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

let axios = require('axios');

let url = axios.defaults.baseURL;

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(), // Generates default index.html
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ // Also generate a test.html
            filename: 'openseadragon.html',
            template: './openseadragon.html'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {}
                    // other vue-loader options go here
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
        },
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
    },

    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: `${url}`
            }
        },
        historyApiFallback: true,
        noInfo: true
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false
    },
    devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
        // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
    module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: '"production"'
            }
        }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            "uglifyOptions": {
                compress: {
                    warnings: false
                },
                sourceMap: true
            }
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true
        })
    ])
}
```

As you can see, the index.html file lies outside the src directory. Is there any way I can get the index.html file to be generated without having to put it into the /src directory?

After making the build I tried running the app on Heroku to make sure it loaded. I get an error like this.

[image: build.js error]
 What's wrong with build.js?

**Here is the original index.html**

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.semanticui.min.css" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nprogress/0.2.0/nprogress.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.4.0/animate.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='src/assets/default.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="./node_modules/vis/dist/vis.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="./node_modules/vis/dist/vis.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.9.3/typeahead.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: #f5f5f5;
        }
        
        .bs-example {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            position: relative;
            margin: 50px;
        }
        
        .typeahead,
        .tt-query .tt-hint {
            border: 2px solid #cccccc;
            border-radius: 8px;
            font-size: 24px;
            height: 30px;
            line-height: 30px;
            outline: medium none;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            width: 396px;
        }
        
        .typeahead {
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
        
        .typeahead:focus {
            border: 2px solid #0097CF;
        }
        
        .tt-query {
            box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
        }
        
        .tt-hint {
            color: #999999;
        }
        
        .tt-dropdown-menu {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            border-radius: 0px;
            box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            margin-top: 1px;
            padding: 8px 0;
            width: 396px;
        }
        
        .tt-suggestion {
            font-size: 20px;
            padding: 3px 20px;
        }
        
        .tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
            background-color: teal;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        
        .tt-suggestion p {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="app">

        <div class="main-wrapper">

            <div class="ui menu navbar fixed" id="main-menu">
                <div style="padding-left:15px;padding-right:10px;">
                    <a href="#/patients"><img src="http://ww1.prweb.com/hello%20logo.jpg" style="width:120px;margin-top:10px;margin-left:10px;" alt=""></a>
                </div>

                <a href="" id="full-screen" class=" item borderless fitted"><i class="maximize icon"></i></a>

                <div class="right menu borderless horizontally fitted">

                    <div class="item ui colhidden borderless">
                        <div class="ui icon input">
                            <input type="text" name="typeahead" id="search_input" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Search patients">
                            <i class="search icon"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <a class="ui dropdown item"><img class="ui avatar image" src="http://www.sarasotaheadshot.com/images/Male-Doctor-White-Coat-Headshot-3.jpg"> Will Kirby
                        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                        <div class="menu">
                            <!-- <div class="item">
                                <i class="comment icon"></i> Announcement
                            </div>
                            <div class="divider"></div> -->
                            <div class="item" onclick="App.logout();">
                                <i class="sign out icon"></i>Logout
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="stage" class="stage stage-padded" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <router-view></router-view>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.10/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.semanticui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/path.js/0.8.4/path.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.7.2/mustache.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nprogress/0.2.0/nprogress.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-fullscreen-plugin/1.1.4/jquery.fullscreen-min.js"></script>

    <script src="dist/build.js"></script>
    <script src="src/js/App.js"></script>

    <script>
        var that = this;
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var url = that.axios.defaults.baseURL;
            App.init();

        });
    </script>
</body>
```

And here is the generated index.html,
**/dist/index.html**

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Webpack App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/build.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin)

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: './index/html', to: 'relative/path/to/dest/' }
    ])
  ]
}
```

[HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin) is other option, and it can automatically inject js script for you

Comment: Thanks, it worked! After generating the build, I deployed the code onto heroku to make sure my app loads. I now get an error when trying to load the page. You can see the error in the edit. Can you please help me out with it?

Comment: Can you show content of your index.html and update webpack config file in your question also?

Comment: Sure! I have added the updated webpack.config.js and the original and the generated index.html files.

Comment: Try changing index.html <script type="text/javascript" src="/build.js"></script>. You might need to change publicPath to `/` in webpack config also

Comment: I tried doing both. The errors are gone, but I now just get a blank html page! Can you please help me out?

Comment: You can check https://github.com/ittus/Credit-Card-Fraud-Detection-Realtime for example. `<script type="text/javascript" src="./build.js"></script>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172773/discussion-between-coderpj-and-ittus).